# Enable select and upload file

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm using News System with TYPO3 v9. and I can't enable `select and upload` on the `Media` tabs.

[image]

I added the following to Page TSConfig, but nothing changed :

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.config.appearance.fileUploadAllowed = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause : `user_upload` has been locked.

File uploads are only possible when the user has access to the folder user_upload. If you restrict the access for the user one can't see the `Select & upload files` any more.